# Semantic mediawiki - Set propery to range of values

Tags: properties, mediawiki, semantics

I'm trying to set a specific property to a non exact value, for example say that I want to define the height of a pine tree to usually between 3-80 m (according to wikipedia). Then I would like to set something like [[Has height::3-80]] (of course this doesn't work) and defining the unit to meters with "custom units". Then I would like to be able to query for example "trees that can reach the height of 70 meters" and the pine tree would be included. I've been searching and trying different angles for hours now and I can't figure it out. Tried with #set_recurring_event but that seems to be only for dates/time. Also understood how to set multiple values for a property with #arraymap but this doesn't seem to help me here. Really would appreciate help with this (it's probably very easy and right in front of me) Thx! COG

Answer (score 0):

There's no such things. But you able to create template, with parameters you want. The you just use code kinda `{{range|min|max|units}}`. For example your range of heights looks like `{{range|3|80|m}}`.